# Update custom product attribute values - Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I have the problem with UPDATING table catalog/product in Magento. I want to update value in column 'custom_product_option' which I added as EAV attribute :

```
 for ($i=0;$i<=sizeof($my_data); $i++){
            $id = $my_data[$i];

            $db_data = array('custom_product_option'=>3);
            $model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id)->addData($db_data);
            try {
                $model->setId($id)->save();
                echo "Data updated successfully.";

            } catch (Exception $e){
                echo $e->getMessage();

            }


        }
```

When I try to UPDATE my new custom value in catalog/product table I get this error:

```
Integrity constraint violation 1062 duplicate entry '44-1-0-2.0000-0' for key '...'
```

I am confused, because I am updating the table, and it behaves like I am inserting new value with same ID. I appreciate if somebody could help.

Comment: please put the full error here...bcoz it contains that database table name so i can tell you the exact problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that `$my_data` is an array of product ids that need to be updated.
If so, try this. It is much faster:

```
$db_data = array('custom_product_option'=>3);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
    $my_data, //array with ids to be updated, 
    $db_data, //array with attributes to be updated, 
    0 //store id for the update : 0 = default values
);
```